# Text Input Value sometimes does't change even though it thows no errors, and seems to work

Tags: javascript, html

So I have a simple program to change the value of an input field every time you blur it. It logs the already used values in an array, an I use that array to check if it's been used. It practically works as intended, but after a few tries it will return true and logs, yet the value wont change.

**Updated Code:**

```
var dftvalue = ['Freddy the Grocer', 'Jack the Fiddler', 'Cane the Sheep Herder', 'Arnold the Fish Monger', 'Luke the Car Salesman', 'Josh the Tailor', 'Carol the Baker', 'Tiara the Nacho Vendor', 'example@email.com', 'Your message here.'];

var logused =  new Array(); //create new array to log the used indexs

function setdftvalue() {
   var newval = dftvalue[Math.floor(Math.random() * 7)];
   if (logused.indexOf(newval) == -1) {
     this.value=newval;
     logused.push(newval);
     console.log(logused);
   } else if (logused.indexOf(newval) >= 0) {
     setdftvalue();
   }
   if (logused.length == 8) {
      for (i=0; i<=7; i++){
        logused.pop();
      }
   }
}
document.getElementById('formname').onblur=setdftvalue;
```

**JSFIDDLE**
https://jsfiddle.net/e5pdz37e/8/

Comment: It still does return something? To me, that looks more like an infinite loop!

Comment: What is requirement ? , expected result ?

Comment: I guess I didn't point out my question good enough :D sorry. The logic works actually, because it will only recurse to get a new value that isn't already in the logused array. I've updated the code to include the array limit and reset it to default state after using/logging every value given. My issue is that after running it a bit the code works, but the value isn't actually painted to the input field sometimes. When I check logused in console it shows the code working just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is unnecessarily complicated. At a high level I would recommend an approach that's more like this:

```
function setdftvalue() {
    if (index === (dftvalue.length - 1)) {
        // Shuffle your names array
        index = -1;
    }

    input.value = dftvalue[++index];
}
```

This way you won't need to use any recursion and make unnecessary function calls. And the only time you'll need to randomize is when you've used up all of your available names.

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/bvaughn/163mqdeL/

**Original answer**

After a few invocations, your function will fill up the `logused` Array, at which point calling it again will do nothing. Actually, worse than nothing - it will recursively call itself without end.

Comment: Below the code I put 'Keeping in mind that I have not yet handled the resetting the array after it's filled all seven index's.' I updated the code since then and added the proper functionality. It will only recurse until it finds a value that isn't logged, if they are all used up then it will empty the log and start from there. My issue not really the logic, but a strange issue with changing the value of the text feild. Sometimes it works, but after a bit it still logs and holds the value, just won't change value.

Comment: Sorry, it was unclear to me from reading your question that you *knew* you had a problem with the way your code was structured and you were asking about *another* problem. Of course the text field value would not be changed with the way the code was before, because that part of the if statement would never be reached once the array filled up.

Comment: I made a fiddle so maybe It's a little more clear the issue. https://jsfiddle.net/e5pdz37e/ I guess im not too good at explaining things XD also dont worry about the Firefox recursion error that will log to console.

Comment: Actually... the Jsfiddle you linked to shows the exact problem I pointed out before. Your Array is full and then your function calls itself endlessly until you have a stack overflow- that error you said to ignore.